# Repulsive force between same charged plates?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

I understand that the attraction force between parallel plates of capacitor is the derivative of stored energy with respect to distance of the plates.
But how could we find the repulsive force between two parallel plates that have the same charge? In this case the net field inside is zero. Any ideas?

I am trying to use this to model electrical levitation.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the field inside the plates is zero. But what about the field outside the plates? Try calculating that first and use the same approach to derive the Force ( derivative of energy).